# Switching sessions in cypress

Tags: automation, cypress, e2e

There's this exact title in the cypress docs: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session#Switching-sessions-inside-tests

But I'm not sure how to implement it.

I currently have a test that signs up a user A, does something, and then another user B signs up (there a reset state here that cleans the session) and verifies something.

I would like to add another it() reusing the sessions from user A and B, is that possible? And how so?

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do right now. Were you able to come up with something?

Comment: Nope, this whole thing wasn't reliable (user A session persisted randomly). Also my company purged the cypress folder eventually.

Comment: Ah ok, appreciate the response